# Can I share my webpage using my IP adress?

Tags: ip, share, html, portforwarding

I made a simple .html file with a .css and I want to share it with some people without having to send the files and explaining how to open them etc. so I was wondering: Is it possible to use my IP and a port so that when they put it in their browser, they get the webpage as if they normally loaded a website? Like this:
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 in their url bar and it would be like they opened my .html file with their browser normally.
Is that possible? If yes: can someone explain how?

Comment: Depends on the way you host it on your pc

Comment: You probably have to forward port 9000 on your home router to your PC. To find out your public IP use something like http://www.whatsmyip.org

Comment: After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting!
I can't answer my own question yet since I'm too new so I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting! So I can just use it with an FTP client to upload it to the webserver and share the link! But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a permanent solution I would look into a hosting provider instead of setting up self hosting. It will enable you to easily deploy out new versions hassle free. 
If you decide to go with your own hosting you have to manage firewall and network configurations on your own which is too involved to explain in this answer.

Comment: Thanks! After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting!
So I can just use it with an FTP client to upload it to the webserver and share the link!
But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, unless you set your pc to act as a server, but that's way more work than sending the files around and explaining how to open them unfortunately.

Check around for some cheap web hosting as a long-term solution, i pay 40 a year for hosting and for how many sites and projects I have on it, it's worth it :)

Comment: Thanks! After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting!
So I can just use it with an FTP client to upload it to the webserver and share the link!
But thanks for your time!

Comment: no worries! p.s. lucky you on the free 50mb, that will go a surprisingly long way!

Answer (score 0):

You should install a web server, configure it and your proxy. Then give them your IP adress.
They will be able to access it via their browser.

Easier to give them a zipped folder by mail.

Comment: Thanks! After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting!
So I can just use it with an FTP client to upload it to the webserver and share the link!
But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found this recently and has been a good tool for collaborating with team members, http://fenixwebserver.com/. They also do the proxy stuff allowing developers to share the webpages easily.

Comment: Thanks! After more research it turns out my ISP provides 50MB free web hosting!
So I can just use it with an FTP client to upload it to the webserver and share the link!
But thanks for your time!